# DC ComicTournament Bracket?

Tags: discussion, scope

I recently asked a question ([Has Batman ever fought Hawkman?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/124622/25784)) the pertained to a single battle of a tournament that was constructed by a kids comic book (I don't remember which one of the top of my head).

I was wondering if I could ask a similar question but have it cover the entire tournament?

Would it be too broad because of the amount of times that some heroes and villains have fought each other?

would it be too broad because of the length of the answers?  I assume that the length of the answers may get rather long.

Comment: Thanks for asking first!

Comment: you bet @Mooz I love this site!  I have not forgotten about this either.  My daughter is going to get that bracket out for me so I should have something in the next couple of days for more questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would strongly suggest that you post each pairing as a separate question. As you've rightly identified, having the entire tournament in a single question is simply going to be too lengthy and complex for a single answer format.

On top of that, having all of the bouts in a single question will make it very hard for the average site user to judge the relative worth of each answer, especially if there are multiple sources being used.

To my mind, it's far better to follow the format you've already used; "**Has X ever fought Y and if so, who won?**" and simply replicate it for all of the bouts.

Comment: should I post links to relate them at the end....?

Comment: @malachi  - Yes, link them and make it clear in the title that it's "Round #1", "Round #2", etc.